# seeing duplicates layout file after run

Tags: android, android-layout

when running apps i am seeing duplicate layout file, which is not delete sometimes. when try to delete this file this error comes out.

I have  **login.xml** file, after running project the adding new xml **login.out.xml.**

[image]

I faced many times such types of problem. so can you guys tell how to generated this duplicate file? when?

Comment: you are compiling your layout file. right click on your project name and from there run your project.

Comment: @Google_Android_Lovers If any answer is helping you then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to run the application while an xml file is currently the open tab on the editor. Just delete the file and clean the project. After that, run the project with a java file as the opened tab on the editor.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3767) is a bug filing about this.

Comment: yes if you use eclipse jee, I've switched to eclipse java that has no xlst processing

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing into the `login.xml` file and after completion of changes you are using ctrl+f11 to run your application at that time the `login.out.xml` file is created, this problem is generated after update ADT plugin to 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395, so first close the `login.out.xml` file and after you can delete this file, sorry for my bad English and see below link for more information.

[How to fix the main.out.xml issue](http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/android-beginner-top-tip-dont-run-from-xml-files/)

[Android: main.out.xml error](http://soft-dev-pro.blogspot.in/2010/03/android-mainoutxml-error.html)